# C++: Why doesn't what() throw an exception?

Tags: c++, exception

In the `std::exception` class and the derived classes from it there is a virtual function called `what()` which doesn't throw an exception. But why doesn't `what()` throw an exception?

Comment: Because that would be horribly bad design.

Comment: Because it is `noexcept`, for one.  It just returns a string, no reason whatsoever to expect it to throw.

Comment: Perhaps read the documentat ion.

Comment: @EdHeal [Show them](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception/what) if you refer to it please.

Answer (score 3):

`what()` is a method that allows you to get string (error message) associated with exception:

See the reference documentation **[`std::exception::what()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception/what)**

It should not throw any exceptions by design.

If you want to throw an exception in C++ go with:

```
throw std::exception("we are going to die");
```